# Difference in between " config " and "defaults" in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, touch

I think its a simple question, but I am new with Sencha Touch...

What is the difference in between " config " and "defaults" in Sencha Touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defaults is an object that applies to all the child components of a parent container. `labelWidth: 100` in the defaults section of a container sets the label width of all its child components to 100.

Configs are the initial values passed to the constructor during the initialization of your class. It cannot be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I think the "defaults" you apply in a container and these properties will be applied in the "config" of her children